# Asp.net Roles Web Api check annotation "authorize" programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I need to check if the current logged user can use a controller method BEFORE calling it.
es:
I am logged as USER (group:users) and i want to check if i am authorized to call "delete()" method with annotation: "[Authorize(Roles='Users')]"

There is a way to solve this? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? because the Authorize annotation does exactly this. If you call it using a user that's not in the "Users" role, the method will return a 401 - unauthorized

Comment: I need to check it before i call it! I need this to create links or not ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the UserManager to check if the user is in a given role.

```
ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
if (UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Users"))
{
    // Do something.
}
```